# Update Buefy component using JavaScript..VueJs

Tags: javascript, buefy

I have the following Buefy component on my .vue file:

```
 <button class="button is-dark alt-dark" slot="trigger">
  <b-icon ref="bellIcon" pack="far" icon="bell" :class="{ 'has-update-mark' : false }"></b-icon>
</button>
```

I want to remove the "pack='far' attribute and update the json object the class is set to true. So my Buefy component will look like this:

```
 <button class="button is-dark alt-dark" slot="trigger">
    <b-icon ref="bellIcon" icon="bell" :class="{ 'has-update-mark' : true }"></b-icon>
 </button>
```

I tried to remove the pack attribute like so:

```
 this.$refs.bellIcon.pack = ""
```

But I got the following error:

```
  Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component
  re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: 
  "pack"
```

So, I do not know how to modify the :class or pack attributes. How do I modify them in javascript? Especially the :class attribute. I didnt even see it in the list of objects when i inspected the "bellIcon" ref. So I really want that one the most. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mutate props that way. If you need to supply a dynamic props to child component, pass a reactive instance. Have a look at the code for further explanation.

```js
Vue.use(Buefy, {
  defaultIconComponent: 'vue-fontawesome',
  defaultIconPack: 'fas',
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
   return {
     pack: "fas", // "pack" is reactive 
    };
  },
  methods: {
   toggleIconFontType() {
        // here the "pack" data is changed
     this.pack = this.pack === "fas" ? "far" : "fas";
      console.info("Icon Pack Changed", {pack: this.pack});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/buefy/0.8.20/buefy.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- when this button is clicked, "toggleIconFontType" is invoked   -->
  <button @click="toggleIconFontType">Click Me</button>
  <button class="button is-dark alt-dark" slot="trigger">
  <!-- Here i am binding pack props with reactive data "pack"  -->
  <b-icon ref="bellIcon" :pack="pack" icon="bell" :class="{ 'has-update-mark' : false }"></b-icon>
</button>
</div>
```